# Exclude key-value pairs from dictionary when creating a new dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

The `create_mileage(exclude=None)` function creates a new two-dimensional dictionary with data from the three-dimensional `VEHICLES` dictionary and the default `"unknown"` value.

The `exclude` parameter can contain a dictionary with key-value pairs to be excluded from the new dictionary. Unfortunately this does not work like this.

Code:

```
VEHICLES = {"car": {
                "VW Polo": {"power": 75,
                            "color": "blue"},
                "BMW 5 series": {"power": 400,
                                 "color": "black"}},
            "truck": {
                "MAN TGL": {"power": 200,
                            "color": "red"},
                "Mercedes-Benz Actros": {"power": 500,
                                         "color": "white"}},
            "bus": {
                "Mercedes-Benz Citaro": {"power": 300,
                                         "color": "yellow"},
                "Solaris Vacanza 13": {"power": 400,
                                       "color": "green"}}
            }


def create_mileage(exclude=None):
    result = dict()
    for vehicle_type, vehicle_model in VEHICLES.items():
        if {vehicle_type: vehicle_model} not in exclude.items(): # Doesn't work
            result[vehicle_type] = dict.fromkeys(vehicle_model, "unknown")
    return result


print(create_mileage({"car": "VW Polo", "truck": "Mercedes-Benz Actros"}))
```

The output should be as follows...

```
{'car': {'BMW 5 series': 'unknown'}, 'truck': {'MAN TGL': 'unknown'}, 'bus': {'Mercedes-Benz Citaro': 'unknown', 'Solaris Vacanza 13': 'unknown'}}
```

...but it is as follows.

```
{'car': {'VW Polo': 'unknown', 'BMW 5 series': 'unknown'}, 'truck': {'MAN TGL': 'unknown', 'Mercedes-Benz Actros': 'unknown'}, 'bus': {'Mercedes-Benz Citaro': 'unknown', 'Solaris Vacanza 13': 'unknown'}}
```

What needs to be changed to make the code work as intended?

Answer (score 1):

`items()` returns a `tuple`, not a `dict`:

```
def create_mileage(exclude=None):
    result = dict()
    eItems = exclude.items()
    for vehicle_type, vehicle_model in VEHICLES.items():
        if (vehicle_type, vehicle_model) not in eItems:
            result[vehicle_type] = dict.fromkeys(vehicle_model, "unknown")
    return result



print(create_mileage({"car": "VW Polo", "truck": "Mercedes-Benz Actros"}))
```

Result:

> {'car': {'VW Polo': 'unknown', 'BMW 5 series': 'unknown'}, 'truck': {'MAN TGL': 'unknown', 'Mercedes-Benz Actros': 'unknown'}, 'bus': {'Mercedes-Benz Citaro': 'unknown', 'Solaris Vacanza 13': 'unknown'}}

Comment: Unfortunately, the result still contains vehicles ("VW Polo", "Mercedes-Benz Actros") to be excluded.

Answer (score 0):

`dict.items()` returns the key:value pairs as tuples, not dictionaries.

```
print({'a':1} in {'a':1,'b':2}.items())
False

print(('a',1) in {'a':1,'b':2}.items())
True
```

You're checking for `{vehicle_type: vehicle_model}`, try checking for `(vehicle_type, vehicle_model)` instead

Comment: Unfortunately, this fix does not change anything in the output.